# Hilbert matrix function in R

Tags: r, function

[image]

I am trying to create a function `hilbert_matrix` that computes the `hilbert_matrix` of dimensions equal to : `dim_mat` with `dim_mat` being a positive integer.

Can someone explain to me why do I get null when I try

```
hilbert_matrix(10).
```

Here is my code :

```
hilbert_matrix <- function(dim_mat) {
  if (!is.numeric(dim_mat) || length(dim_mat) != 1 || dim_mat <= 0 || !is.integer(dim_mat)) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  
  hilbert <- matrix(0, nrow = dim_mat, ncol = dim_mat)
  
  for (i in 1:dim_mat) {
    for (j in 1:dim_mat) {
      hilbert[i, j] <- 1 / (i + j - 1)
    }
  }
  
  return(hilbert)
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not know what you are doing, but are you looking for somethig like `dm <- c(3,3); 1/(.col(dm) + .row(dm))`?? Here you could change the 3 to 10 to match the matrix you want??

Comment: I added a picture of what I want. I do not understand why I get. NULL when I try hilbert_matrix(10) given that 10 correspond to the criteria that I have added.

Comment: I have given you an explanation below

Comment: i can not test at the moment, but I suspect the `!is.integer()` statement. try `typeof(10)` and see that 10 is represented as double, unless you explicitly specify it as integer with `10L`.

Answer (score 2):

The `NULL` is returned because `10` is not an integer. Note that in the `if` statement, there is a condition `!is.integer(dim_mat)` which evaluates to  `TRUE` thus returning `NULL` to use your function, consider passing only integers:

```
hilbert_matrix(3)
NULL

hilbert_matrix(3L) # Appending `L` to 3
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
[2,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000
[3,] 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000

hilbert_matrix(as.integer(3)) # explicit coercing to integer
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
[2,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000
[3,] 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```

The best way to check as to whether the number is an integer is if `as.integer(x) == x` or `floor(x) == x` etc, but not directly `is.integer(x)`.

Anyway whatever you are doing is equivalent to:

```
hilbert_mat2 <- function(dim_mat){
 if(!is.numeric(dim_mat) | length(dim_mat) != 1 | dim_mat <= 0 | floor(dim_mat) != dim_mat) return (NULL)
 dm <- c(dim_mat, dim_mat)
 1/(.col(dm) + .row(dm))
}



hilbert_mat2(3)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000
[2,] 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
[3,] 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77403992/12158757) has explained the reason you got `NULL`, so not necessary to discuss about it again here, but the code below is just another shorter implementation of `Hilbert` matrix.

Try `outer`

```
hilbert_matrix <- function(n) 1 / (outer(1:n, 1:n, `+`) - 1)
```

and you will obtain, for example

```
> hilbert_matrix(3)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
[2,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000
[3,] 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000

> hilbert_matrix(5)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
[2,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667
[3,] 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667 0.1428571
[4,] 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667 0.1428571 0.1250000
[5,] 0.2000000 0.1666667 0.1428571 0.1250000 0.1111111
```